# NSString time format to int64_t

Tags: objective-c, ios, game-center

I have an NSString that represents a time in `mm:ss` format. How do i convert it in `int64_t` so i can submit it as a score in game center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to be rigorous you could use an NSDateFormatter to convert to an NSDate then get an NSTimeInterval from that; if you wanted to be more direct then you might try something as simple as:

```
NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
if([components count] != 2)
{
    // some error condition
    return;
}

int64_t totalSeconds = ([[components objectAtIndex:0] integerValue] * 60) +
                             [[components objectAtIndex:1] integerValue];
```